# AttributeError: 'ApplicantEducation' object has no attribute '_state'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is how i constructed my model:

**Model.py**

```
    class ApplicantEducation(models.Model):
        applicant_info = models.ForeignKey(ProfileInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        degree_details = models.ForeignKey(DegreeDetails, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
        marks_percentage = models.FloatField(max_length=5, default=0.0)
        institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        affilation_with = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
        date_completion = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.applicant_info)
    
        def __init__(self, applicant_info = None, degree_details = None):
            applicant_info = ProfileInfo.info_id
            degree_details = DegreeDetails.id
```

Anybody, who can figure this out??

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `__init__` of your model without calling `__init__` of your Base class, e.g. you need to explicitly call it with `super`:

```py
class ApplicantEducation(models.Model):
    # fields
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...
```

I have no idea what you are doing with your `applicant_info` and `degree_details` arguments passed to your constructor (probably you want to assign them to the corresponding fields of your models)

Comment: Yes I want to assign them to the corresponding fields of your models.